# Data binding not working in nested directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to angular world.I am trying to create an app with reusable nested directives.
Here is a link to my code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/T2CNKQkLEoxjb3TGdp67?p=preview

I have created two containers and bound them to two set of data.Now if I click the buttons it should show me the data bound to parent scope.But it's showing only one set of data.When i debug it seems that both the buttons are bound to one single scope.How do it separate the scope of this two buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with some help.
I needed to use ng-click instead of onclick()
If anyone is facing the same problem here is the updated code.[Working Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/0cgq6Auk2XJfWiOHSFEi?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since there is so much commented code in the plunkr, it is a bit confusing at what you are asking.  However one big problem is the line:

```
<container data="{{pie2}}"></container>
```

The curly braces `{{` tell Angular to write out your variable as a string, so you lose any reference to the variable itself.  Instead you would want:

```
<container data="pie2"></container>
```

And the scope of the directive would become:

```
    scope :{
        data:"="
    },
```

That will help you get the reference you are expecting. Let me know if this gets you on the right path. Or if you can simplify/clarify your quesiton further.

Comment: hi checketts,Sorry for the clumsy code.A more clear version I posted yesterday is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317322/how-to-separate-scopes-of-buttons-inside-a-reusable-directive).I got the answer.Actually i was using onclick() instead of using ng-click.