# How to separate scopes of buttons inside a reusable directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to have a reusable directive with several buttons.But my problem is when I try to use the same directive multiple times the buttons binds to one single scope.
For example see the code below:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <test></test>
  <test></test>
</body>
```

Code for test directive is

```
app.directive("test",function(){

return{
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
          },
    template:"<input type='button' value='click me!' onclick='clickD()'>",
    controller:function($scope){
        clickD=function()
        {
            alert($scope.$id);
        }
    }
}
})
```

You can see the example here as well [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lTnlqZL0TqY81GkJOFkw?p=preview)

Now How do I separately the scopes.
My actual problem is pretty clumsy so i simplified it till this level.Please help me !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  use `ng-click` and not `onclick`, also place the `clickD()` function on your `$scope`

```
app.directive("test", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        template: "<input type='button' value='click me!' ng-click='clickD()'>",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.clickD = function () {
                alert($scope.$id);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**[updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/41CiEQTAN8bvQrszI6sW?p=preview)**